# How to determine when multiple ajax callbacks have completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

There are a couple of questions of this exact nature already asked.  One of which received no answer, one of which suggested exactly what I am trying, without success.

Here's what I am wanting to do:

Function a() will be called 1 to numerous times.
Function b() performs an async call.

```
    for (i=0; i<=something; i++) {
        function a() {
            function b();  //makes async call
        }
    }

// at this point, execution continues, 
// even though all function b()'s async
// calls are still "pending".
```

Because of the async call in function b(), function a() is itself, for all practical purposes also async.

I need some way of knowing when all of function b()'s async calls have completed.

I tried this:

```
var callCount=0;

for (i=0; i<=something; i++) {
    function a() {
        callCount++;
        function b(callCount);
    }
}
```

I then have function b()'s async callback function decrement callCount, and do this:

```
var callCount=0;

for (i=0; i<=something; i++) {
    function a() {
        callCount++;
        function b(callCount); // b()'s callback decrements callCount by 1;
    }
}

while (callCount > 0) {
}

// now continue
```

But at the conclusion of the for() loop, callCount still contains the number of calls, and never decrements, resulting in an infinite loop.

Is callCount immutable inside b()'s callback function?

IS there any way to detect when a multiple number of async calls have all completed?  I'm using both jquery .ajax() and .get().

Comment: Give a good read to [promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) and [deferred Object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object)

Comment: @AldoRomo88.  Wow!  I gave both just a quick once-over, and I'm totally turned on right now, man!  Especially by deferredObject, since it's in jQuery, there's polyfill for older browswers!  What about Promises?  What does browswer support for these look like at the moment?  Thanks for the direction.  It will definitely help if there simply is no way to do what I am trying to do.

Comment: See the Browser Compatibility table at the end of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: And, I swear, SO ought to require one to not only explain, but defend one's downvotes.  Jimminey.

Comment: @Barmar - also an excellent help.  IE - no support.  Why am I not surprised by this!  ;-)

Comment: Just use jQuery deferred and you should be fine.

Comment: When you passed callCount into b(), you passed the current value of callCount, not a reference to it. Therefore, b() is operating on a completely different variable, so decrementing it does nothing outside the function.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was afraid of.  I had previously googled "Does javascript pass by reference?", and that was the consensus there, but there was a difference between primitive types and objects.  Objects pass "copy of a reference", but primitive types, by value (I think it was).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After promises and deferred introduction... all you need is to keep an array of promises and use $.when and apply

```
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
  console.log('All ajax calls completed');
});
```

Please se this [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AldoRomo88/bw49k5g3/), just open your console.

Comment: If I put this array in function b(), how do I persist it between calls?  If I put it in function a(), how do I make it available to function b()? @AldoRomo88.

Comment: Know I think that you need to understand closures, give a read to this articles 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures
http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/